Save and load random number generator state
I am doing number-crunching on a large set of numbers with a random aspect to it. Due to it's long runtime, I need a way to stop and restart the process with the same state, esp. the random number generator should continue at its last state (it needs to be reproducible).
Considering a Java random number generator, I want to "save" and later "load" its state, meaning it should continue generating reproducible identical random numbers, although it is a different instance of a random number generator:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final java.util.Random prng1 = new java.util.Random(4);
        int lastInt = 0;
        // Generate arbitrary amount of random numbers
        for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
            lastInt = prng1.nextInt();
        }
        // TODO: Save state
        // TODO: Load state later, continuing with the same random numbers as if it were the same random number generator
        final java.util.Random prngRestored = new java.util.Random(lastInt);

        System.out.println("Should be identical: " + prng1.nextInt() + " =!= " + prngRestored.nextInt());
    }

Is it possible to achieve this, and if so how?
One idea is to also save the amount of generated numbers, and let the "restored" prng with the same seed as the initial prng iterate through the same amount of numbers, to get to the same internal state, however that seems like wasting computing power.

You can do this, but it will very much depend on the implementation details. You can get the current seed using reflection, and reverse the initialScramble, then you can pass it as the seed of the new Random object. This is specific to this particular implementation of Random.

One option is to use either a cryptographic hash function (where output numbers may repeat) or a cryptographic encryption (where numbers will not repeat). Process numbers in order: 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and keep track of how far you have got. You will need to keep the various cryptographic constants, such as the key, the same to repeat the same numbers, or change them for a different set of numbers.

This question is similar to: How do I get the seed from a Random in Java?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458383/java-random-numbers-using-a-seed

I tried following options:

Retrieving the seed via reflection as stated in the linked answer does not work for me (yielding a java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException)
Creating a new prng with the same seed and progressing it to the same state
Serializing, (saving & loading), de-serializing the same object

For me, the 1st option seems to be the most problematic, relying on implementation specifics. The 2nd option is not elegant in that it wastes computing time. The 3rd option seems to be the closest to my requirements.
Following I attach my test source-code for anyone running into the same requirements:
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class PrngSaveLoadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        long initialSeed = 4;
        final Random prng1 = new Random(initialSeed);
        int amountOfSteps = 0;
        // Generate arbitrary amount of random numbers
        for (int i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {
            prng1.nextInt();
            amountOfSteps++;
        }
        // TODO: Save state
        // TODO: Load state later, continuing with the same random numbers as if it were the same random number generator

        // Option 1: Use reflection to get internal seed of prng1 - does not work, throws exception
        //final Random prngRestoredBySeed = new Random(getSeed(prng1));
        //System.out.println("Should be identical: " + prng1.nextInt() + " =!= " + prngRestoredBySeed.nextInt());

        // Option 2: Progress the second prng instance the same amount of numbers - works
        final Random prngRestoredByProgress = new Random(initialSeed);
        progressPrng(prngRestoredByProgress, amountOfSteps);
        System.out.println("Should be identical: " + prng1.nextInt() + " =!= " + prngRestoredByProgress.nextInt());

        // Option 3: Serialize, save, load, deserialize the prng instance
        byte[] serializedPrng = serializePrng(prng1);
        Random prngRestoredBySerialization = deserializePrng(serializedPrng);
        System.out.println("Should be identical: " + prng1.nextInt() + " =!= " + prngRestoredBySerialization.nextInt());

    }

    /**
     * See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29278559/1877010
     */
    private static long getSeed(Random prng) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = Random.class.getDeclaredField("seed");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        AtomicLong scrambledSeed = (AtomicLong) field.get(prng);
        long theSeed = scrambledSeed.get();
        return (theSeed ^ 0x5DEECE66DL);
    }

    private static void progressPrng(Random prng, long amountOfSteps) {
        for (long i = 1; i <= amountOfSteps; i++) {
            prng.nextInt();
        }
    }

    private static byte[] serializePrng(Random prng) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(128);
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {
            oos.writeObject(prng);
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    private static Random deserializePrng(byte[] serializedPrng) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedPrng);
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bais)) {
            // Method for deserialization of object
            return ((Random) in.readObject());
        }
    }
}


Java's Random class is implemented with a simple linear congruential generator (LCG). The implication of this is you can implement your progressPrng(N) in O(log(N)) steps instead of O(N) as in your method.
